# Geometry involving similarity

Tags: geometry

PRVW is a parallelogram . UV = 14cm , 
RT= 4cm , TV = 8cm , ST= 6cm , RS = 7cm, PR = x cm, 
Given that RTS is similar to VTU ,
PQS is similar to WQU

Find value of x if

area of PQS : area WQU = 9

[image]

My workings -

$PQ/WQ = QS/QU = PS/WU = 3/1$

From here I'm stuck and not sure how to continue ...

Thanks for the help

Comment: If the ratio of the areas is 9:1 then the ratio of the sides are 3: 1.  So UW = (7 + x )/3 and WV = x so UW = 14 - x.  So (7+x)/2 = 14 - x.

Answer (score 2):

First show that **all the triangles are similar**.

Now use the fact that *if two triangles are similar, then the ratio of their areas is square of ratio of their sides*.

Also, $WV = x$, since $PRVW$ is parallelogram.

Therefore we have the ratio of sides of $\triangle QPS \text{ and } \triangle QWU$ equal $3:1$

$$\dfrac{7+x}{14-x} = \dfrac{3}{1}$$ 
or 
$$\dfrac{7+x}{3} = 14-x$$

Answer (score 0):

The triangles are clearly similar.

If the ratio of the areas is 9:1 then the ratio of the sides are 3: 1. So UW = PS/3 = (7 + x )/3 and WV = PR = x so UW = 14 - x. So (7+x)/2 = 14 - x.